# JDO unique fields in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

According to [**this**](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-java/ctkDe3MakHo), Google App Engine's JDO implementation does not support JDO @Unique annotation. Is this still so?

For example, I have this class:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    @Persistent
    private String email;
    @Persistent
    private String sessionToken;
    ...
}
```

Obviously the `key` is unique, but I also wanted to have unique `email` and `sessionToken`. If @Unique is not supported, what's the best way to "simulate" this behaviour in terms of both simplicity and performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [issue linked from that](http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=22&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20FoundIn%20TargetRelease%20Owner%20Summary) can't be clearer. JDO is not the problem .... the problem is the underlying GAE/Datastore database not supporting it (and if the datastore doesn't support it then there's no way an API can magically impose something in the datastore). That issue also gives a workaround

Comment: Thanks. I did understand the probelm is with "GAE's implementation" as I stated in my question and not with anything else... I wanted to know if it was still so (because the issue is from 2009), and whether the workaround they give is atually the best solution...

Comment: I'm not referring to "GAE's implementation" of JDO. It's not their JDO plugin either. It's their Datastore. And the javadocs for their Datastore have no way of defining unique keys either. The workarounds there are still perfectly valid and as good as there is, or just do a search for "appengine unique key" and get the same basic ideas (some in Python)