# Enforce unique field in appengine datastore (java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, datanucleus

I have a User class with a String field emailAddress, on which I want to enforce uniqueness.  I was having difficulty getting the available suggested solutions to work, so I wrote the following process which seems to work, using a separate class with the unique field as its primary key.

Whilst it seems to work, it smells because I'm intentionally creating an exception when nothing incorrect happens (by trying to retrieve a non-existent EmailAddress object).

Can anyone comment on whether this method will work reliably, in particular across multiple appengine instances.

Thanks.

Firstly, I have the User class:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class User {
  public User(String emailAddress, String otherData) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    this.otherData = otherData;
  }

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Key key;

  @Persistent
  private String emailAddress;

  @Persistent
  private String otherData;
}
```

I then have an EmailAddress class, using the email address as the primary key:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class EmailAddress {
  public EmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
    this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
  }

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent
  private String emailAddress;
}
```

Usage of these classes is then as follows:

```
public class UserManager {

  public User createUser(String email, String otherData) {
    User user = new User(emailAddress, otherData);
    EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress(email);

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();

    User persistedUser = null;  

    try {
      tx.begin();
      EmailAddress testEmailAddress = null;
      try {
        testEmailAddress = pm.getObjectById(EmailAddress.class, email);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        //
      }
      if (null != testEmailAddress) {
        throw new RuntimeException("That email address already has an account");
      }
      pm.makePersistent(emailAddress);
      persistedUser  = pm.makePersistent(user);
      txn.commit();
      return persistedUser;
    } finally {
      if (txn.isActive()) {
        txn.rollback();
      }
      pm.close();
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: From where did the `datastore` object come from ?

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadGelbana - typos fixed.

Comment: Trying to answer your question, have you tried the `@Unique` annotation ? http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/orm/constraints.html#unique

Comment: Appreciate your help @MuhammadGelbana, but from this http://stackoverflow.com/q/15686986/1052019 and DataNucleus' reply therein, I'm pretty certain that won't do it.  Hence the mucking around I'm trying in my question.